# Accessing the value of input using global variable in a function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, global-variables

```js
var num = Number(document.querySelector("#check").value);
               
function printResult() {
  //var num = Number(document.querySelector("#check").value);
  console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Enter a positive number</p>
  <input type="text" name="number" id="check" />
  <button onclick="return printResult()">Chek Number</button>
</body>
```

well the variable `num` declared inside the `printResult()` is working fine, but when i declare it outside the function, it is not working. The result in console shows `0`.
Please tell me why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Because when defined outside the statement runs only once. When defined inside the statement runs everytime button is clicked.